# Show that entire function is constant.

Tags: complex-analysis, entire-functions

$f$ is an entire function and $f(z) = i$ when $z = \left(1+ \frac kn \right)+i$  for every positive integer $k$. $n$ is fixed.

How can we conclude that $f$ is constant?

Is there any result about entire function with infinite zeros.

(If it was true for all postive $n$ also then it was easy, I also doubt that there is typographical error in given question. But I want to confirm)

Comment: By taking Infinite product, one can construct entire functions having zero precisely at the given points ( if the points are given as a sequence that do not accumulate) in the plane. Therefore, it n is fixed, there exists non constant entire functions g(z) = f(z)-i that vanishes if and only if z = 1+ k/n + i for all positive integer k.

Comment: I suspect $f$ is bounded, because even for large $z$ (of the right form), $f(z)=i$.

Comment: I should have thought counterexample.

Answer (score 2):

You can't conclude this. For instance we could have $f(z) = i e^{2\pi i n(z-i-1)}$ or similar.

Comment: thanks. My friend and I just did the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

No, we can’t: take $f(z)=\sin(2n\pi(z-1-i))+i$.

Answer (score 0):

People have already given counterexamples. You might note that someone's well  known theorem says that if $(z_n)$ and $(a_n)$ are any sequences with $z_n\ne z_m$ ($n\ne m$) and $z_n\to\infty$ then there exists an entire function $f$ with $f(z_n)=a_n$.

Maybe it's a typo; of course if you swap the roles of $n$ and $k$ it's true. It's also true if you add a suitable growth condition $|f(z)|\le ce^{\alpha|z|}$ for small enough $\alpha$ (I forget exactly how small, I *think* it's $\alpha<1/n$.)